# Как правильно запускать strapi с postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, strapi

Я устанавливаю strapi командой:

```
 npx create-strapi-app myprj
```

Далее выбираю:

```
custom > TS > postgres > dbname > 127.0.0.1 > 5432 > denis > mypassword > N
```

Т.е. указываю

имя БД **dbname**,
хост **127.0.0.1**,
порт **5432**,
имя юзера **denis**,
пароль **mypassword**,
отказываюсь от ssl

Далее, запускаю postgresql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Затем:

```
CREATE ROLE denis WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword' CREATEDB;
```

Потом:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname TO denis;
```

На всё получаю ответы, что все ок, но после того, как пытаюсь запустить strapi получаю:

```
debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-01-06 15:18:20.275] error: create table "strapi_migrations" ("id" serial primary key, "name" varchar(255), "time" timestamp) - нет доступа к схеме public
error: create table "strapi_migrations" ("id" serial primary key, "name" varchar(255), "time" timestamp) - нет доступа к схеме public
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что скорее всего, где то проблемы с правами, вероятней всего, но я только начал изучать strapi и postgresql и пока полный ноль.

Я долго искал ответ в поисковиках, но не смог найти решения свой проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

Не знаю, на сколько это правильно, но если указать в файле *папка нашего проекта*/config/database.ts (в моём случае .ts)
в строке

```
user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'denis'),
```

Заменить имя на `postgres` (дефолтный суперпользовтель в postgresql), а строкой ниже поставить пароль, например `qwerty`, затем

```
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'qwerty';
```

То всё работает. Сомневаюсь, что это правильный подход.
Куда разумней дать все нужные права определенному пользователю и использовать его, но я пока не знаю как это сделать.

Тем не менее, это решение заставило запускаться мой strapi с postgresql